# ambuigity on function call in julia

Tags: julia, ambiguity

I have this error

```
ERROR: MethodError: vcat(::Array{Real,2}, ::TrackedArray{…,Array{Float32,2}}) is ambiguous. Candidates:
  vcat(364::AbstractArray, x::Union{TrackedArray, TrackedReal}, xs::Union{Number, AbstractArray}...) in Tracker at C:\Users\Henri\.julia\packages\Tracker\6wcYJ\src\lib\array.jl:167
  vcat(A::Union{AbstractArray{T,2}, AbstractArray{T,1}} where T...) in Base at abstractarray.jl:1296
Possible fix, define
  vcat(::Union{AbstractArray{T,2}, AbstractArray{T,1}} where T, ::Union{TrackedArray{T,1,A} where A<:AbstractArray{T,1} where T, TrackedArray{T,2,A} where A<:AbstractArray{T,2} where T}, ::Vararg{Union{AbstractArray{T,2}, AbstractArray{T,1}} where T,N} where N)
```

Telling me that two `vcat()` functions are ambiguous. I want to use the `Base.vcat()` function but using it explicitly throws the same error. Why is that ? And what is this "possible fix" proposed by the error throw?

Moreover, when I call manually each line in the REPL no error is thrown. I do not understand this behavior. This only happens when vcat() is in a function called inside another function. Like in my example below.

Here is a code that reproduces the error:

```
using Flux

function loss(a, b, net, net2)
    net2(vcat(net(a),a))

end

function test()    
    opt = ADAM()
    net = Chain(Dense(3,3))
    net2 = Chain(Dense(6,1))
    L(a, b) = loss(a, b, net, net2)

    data = tuple(rand(3,1), rand(3,1))
    xs = Flux.params(net)
    gs = Tracker.gradient(() -> L(data...), xs)
    Tracker.update!(opt, xs, gs)
end
```

Comment: Can you provide a whole minimal working code please?

Comment: Hello, sorry I was a bit p***ed off when I wrote the post. I added a quick example but it uses the package Flux. Hope it's not a problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Using Julia 1.1 and Flux v0.8.3, I have no errors launching your code. Which Julia version are you running ?

Comment: Flux is 0.8.2 and Julia 1.1. I just ran the code again and I get no error... Before that I used `] update Flux` so I guess it was the source of the error. I need to see if this happens still in my main project.

Comment: Probably your `Flux` package was outdated ;)

Comment: Well turns out that it happens still. I'll make up another working example tomorrow.

Comment: @J.Khamphousone Okay I modified again my question. This time the error should be consistently reproducible. Can you try it ?

Comment: Yes I can reproduce it. I've managed to fix vcat by changing your `loss function` with this: `net2(vcat(net(a),Float32.(a)))` because `vcat` couldn't concatenate as `net(a)` was a `Float32 Array` and `a` a `Float64` one. Then `L(data...)` is a TrackedArray of 1 element whereas I think you need a `Float32` that's why I finally replace `loss function` by `net2(vcat(net(a),Float32.(a)))[1]`.
As I'm not totally familiar with Flux package, can you confirm this is what you needed?

Comment: Yes ok that worked. In the example I gave it's because rand() makes Float64, in my project the other array was an array of Real. So the fix worked too. Thank you, how can I promote your comment to an answer ?

Comment: ;) I've added an answer summarizing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned in comments with Henri.D, we've managed to fix it by being carreful with the type of `a` which was an `Array` of `Float64`, default type returned by `rand` whereas `net(a)` returned a `TrackedArray` of `Float32` and made impossible to `vcat` it with `a`.

> I've managed to fix `vcat` by changing your loss function with this: `net2(vcat(net(a),Float32.(a)))` because `vcat` couldn't concatenate as `net(a)` was a `Float32 Array` and `a` a `Float64` one. Then `L(data...)` is a `TrackedArray` of 1 element whereas I think you need a `Float32` that's why I finally replace `loss function` by `net2(vcat(net(a),Float32.(a)))[1]`